# Threeparttable Captions and addfontfeatures

Tags: tables, fonts, threeparttable

Consider the following MWE which attempts to use old style figures by default, except for tables where lining figures should be employed, and do so in combination with the `threeparttable` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional, OldStyle}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document} 
 \begin{table}
  \caption{I am a long caption to illustrate the purpose of a three 
           part table}
  \addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Lining}}
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr} 
   $m$ &    2 &    3 &    5 &   10 &   15 &   30 & 100  \\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

 \begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{I am a long caption to illustrate the purpose of a three 
            part table.}
   \addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Lining}}
   \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr} 
    $m$ &    2 &    3 &    5 &   10 &   15 &   30 & 100  \\
   \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the first case everything is as expected: the table number in the caption is old style whereas the numbers in the table are lining numbers.  However, for the three part variant the table number in the caption is not old style.  Is there a simple solution here?

Comment: The easy solution is to add the caption package.  Otherwise one would have to dig into threeparttable to edit its custom caption.

Comment: This seems like a very nice solution to me!  Please post and I will accept.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: I have a slight inclination not to close the question just in case someone in the future wishes to do a more detailed investigation into threeparttable and propose a direct fix; it is possible that using caption is not an option for everyone.